# Simple HTTP server for key-value lookup

Tags: redis, httpserver

I am looking for a simple HTTP server which accepts (only GET) commands, queries the redis DB with a key and sends the reply (value) back in text format. My only requirement is that the server is very lightweight and can access a backend DB. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean like a reverse proxy forwarding service?

Comment: Edited my question. Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Webdis](http://webd.is/).

> Webdis is a simple HTTP server which forwards commands to Redis and sends the reply back using a format of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

I recently looked for the same kind of HTTP server.

As mentioned by Evandro you can try **Webdis** or you can go for Nginx with some modules.

In your case, for GET requests only, you can install Nginx with the [HttpRedis](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRedisModule) module.
If later your requirements evolve, you can always go for **HttpRedis2Module** which support all the Redis commands.

I personally use the **HttpLuaModule** with the [lua-resty-redis](https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-redis) module and **lua-cjson.**
Once you got the HttpLuaModule running it's really easy to add new lua-modules and to extend the capabilities of Nginx. The **resty-redis** module let you add some logic between the HTTP request handling and your Redis queries using lua. You also have a large number of examples on the module setup and usage on github.
Adding **cjon** let you return JSON instead of raw text.

Answer (score 1):

Use Webdis as suggested or Mod_redis (module for Redis) with nginx or apache2 server as per your requirements.